# How to get json response from Payment.create in PayPal Python REST API

Tags: python, rest, paypal

I'm a little confused by the payments section of the [Python PayPal REST API documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#payments)

It states that you can make a call to `paypalrestsdk.Payment` something like this:

```
payment = Payment({
  "intent": "sale",
  "payer": {
    "payment_method": "credit_card",
    "funding_instruments": [{
      "credit_card": {
        "type": "visa",
        "number": "4417119669820331",
        "expire_month": "11",
        "expire_year": "2018",
        "cvv2": "874",
        "first_name": "Joe",
        "last_name": "Shopper",
        "billing_address": {
          "line1": "52 N Main ST",
          "city": "Johnstown",
          "state": "OH",
          "postal_code": "43210",
          "country_code": "US" }}}]},
  "transactions": [{
    "amount": {
      "total": "7.47",
      "currency": "USD",
      "details": {
        "subtotal": "7.41",
        "tax": "0.03",
        "shipping": "0.03"}},
    "description": "This is the payment transaction description." }]})

payment.create()  # return True or False
```

Then it says that there is a response that:

> Returns a payment object along with the state of the payment and sale. The response includes a payment ID that uniquely identifies the transaction.

However, `payment.create()` just returns a Boolean. 
So how do I retrieve the response JSON that it describes?

Comment: Your link goes to the docs of the REST API docs not to docs of the python lib `paypalrestsdk`. They behave differently. Basically in the lib the `payment` object will change on a successful `create()`.

Comment: Yea sorry about that, you can select your language of choice for the examples on the top right of the page, but I don't think the url preserves the selection. Anyways, you are correct! The fields described in the response section are a part of the payment object after calling .create().  I tried a dir(payment) before asking the question but they don't appear because they are part of some internal __data__ dictionary that I'm not familiar with how it works.  Either way, if you'd like to write up an answer I would gladly accept it.